# Ресурсы для изучения языка срезов aspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Подскажите полезные сервисы для изучения и правильного написания срезов aspectJ. Не могу найти толковые сайты/приложения

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop + доп материалы в конце статьи + код на гитхабе

Comment: @AlekseiGaile , спасибо!